# Black ABS DWV cleanout plug lubricant?

Tags: drain-waste-vent

What is the best lubricant for a threaded black ABS DWV cleanout plug? Needs to be long-lasting and not deteriorate the ABS.

Comment: You sure about that PVC? Black is almost always ABS in that service. Not the same chemistry.

Comment: I use silicone grease and have not noticed any deterioration.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Ecnerwal is chemistry really a concern in this situation, though, given that a lubricant is likely to be as safe for ABS as it is for PVC?

Comment: Oops! Of course, I meant to say ABS. For clarification, the threads on these plugs frequently get chewed up in service, so Teflon pipe tape is not the most robust solution. Our landscaper used Teflon tape on one I recently removed, and it was ripped up so badly by the uneven plug threads that it was practically useless. I was leaning toward some sort of grease, but wanted to make sure I selected one that didn't make the situation worse.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place to use teflon thread sealing tape. It's extremely non-reactive and slippery and designed to seal threads.